# Am I calculating average income per hour by day of week correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, average, datediff, weekday

[data table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSqck.png)

Use a query to calculate average income per hour by day of week.

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(date_start_time), SUM(total_income)/SUM(DATEDIFF((hour, 
date_start_time, date_end_time) AS avg_income
FROM Deliveries
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(date_start_time)
```

Things to know:

- Entry_id is a unique key for each time the employee comes into the office
- There will be many records of the same user_id if an employee comes into the office repeatedly
- Tasks completed will most likely stay unused in this question

Am I appropriately answering this question?

Things I am concerned about:

1) Does DATEDIFF only return an integer value? If thats the case, then to have a better estimation of the avg_income does this mean we should use DATEDIFF(minutes, ..., ...) and then calculate the hours with decimal places from that integer?

2) Are people working overnight shifts something that I need to worry about? How much more complicated would it make this query?

3) Moving onward if I was asked to "calculate the average earnings per hour during 9am to 5pm" does this mean I need to calculate this for each individual employee... or for each individual hour (ie. ultimately am I grouping by hour or by user_ID)?

Comment: Incidentally, pay is never FLOAT. It's why DECIMAL was invented.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use timediff()

2) You will not only need to consider overnight shifts but you will need to consider overtime pay if they work > 40 hours in between the week start date and the week end date for a given week. This is only if employees are paid different hourly rates for these (ex.time and a half).  If this is a factor then you will need to roll up your sleeves because it will be a full algorithm.

3) This depends on what you are trying to find the average by (user, day, etc.) but a simple way would be to just nest your select and grab an avg().

```
select avg(earnings) overall_average from 
(select user, [calculated_earnings] as earnings from [table] where [conditions])

select avg(earnings) overall_average from 
(select weekday, [calculated_earnings] as earnings from [table] where [conditions])
```

Comment: You need direction from whoever requested this on how they would like you to handle "outside of business hours".  I am guessing though they want the total earnings for the day / 8 hours.

Comment: wait...I see what you are getting at.  You are actually taking time logs and summing them, then dividing the earnings by that.  If that is the case then don't worry about overnight shifts since they simply want to know how many $/hour people are making

Comment: I'm guessing you would want the average $/hour per user.  But I do not have the requirements

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow if I have some time.  Is this some sort of class assignment?

Comment: No I'm not in school. Just a practice problem set a friend sent me to grow out of the beginner SQL stage and more into intermediate level querying